# Commands or Expressions?

Tags: command, expression, rust

On one hand, it seems that all commands in Rust return the unit type, which means that Rust includes only expressions (because that commands don't yield a value, by definition). On the other, Rust is an imperative language. Does Rust have commands?

If not - loops, blocks, etc...  are expressions?

Comment: I'm not sure your question has the right scope for SO but yes, [loops and blocks are expressions](http://is.gd/dOZsgf)

Comment: You don't have a clear question - what are you trying to ask? What is a "command"? I'm more familiar with the dichotomy of "statement" vs "expression". Maybe you could put some sample code that shows what you mean?

Comment: There is a proposal for loops to become first-class expressions in Rust. See, for example, https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/961.

Answer (score -1):

I think Rust is considered to be a command-expression programming language. This means expressions change the state of the program (like commands), and commands have a value. If it isn't something that can be used, then it is the unit type. I could be totally wrong.